# HTML Navigation bar pushing page content downwards

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my webpage that I have made, the entire page content would be pushed down by the navigation bar. I have used fullpage.js but the navigation bar would push down the entire page content, including the text and images. How can I fix this issue? The problem with the images can be shown on the third slide.

Thank you.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.overlay {
  height: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover,
.overlay a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay {
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  .overlay a {
    font-size: 20px
  }
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #37675D!important;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #37675D!important;
}

body {
  background-color: #abf0d1;
}

span.stickynav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 50px;
  top: 0 px;
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
}

.container-fluid,
.container-lg,
.container-md,
.container-sm,
.container-xl {
  width: 75%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#section1 {
  background-image: url(images/pak1.jpg);
  background: no-repeat center scroll;
}

#section2 {
  background-image: url(images/pak2.jpg;);
  background: no-repeat center scroll;
  padding: 6% 0 0 0;
}

#section3 {
  background-image: url(images/pak3.jpg);
  background: no-repeat center scroll;
  padding: 6% 0 0 0;
}

#section4 {
  background-image: url(imgs/bg4.jpg);
  background: no-repeat center scroll;
  padding: 6% 0 0 0;
}

.paklogo {
  padding-right: 10px;
  z-index: 999!important;
}

#jema {
  padding-left: 100px;
}

.fp-tableCell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px!important;
}

#jama {
  padding-left: 100px;
}

div.fontsize {
  font-size: 200%;
}

input[type=text],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

.containerform {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 75%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.8/fullpage.min.css" integrity="sha256-+dIh4jG2jQTHZwW81yUo8h6tzXWcNumyNL5XPZbwp1E=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <div class="overlay-content">
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="junior.html">submenu1</a>
      <a href="senior.html">submenu2</a>
      <a href="contact.html">submenu3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <span class="stickynav" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
  <img style="float: right;" src="images/dummy.png" alt="dummy" class="stickynav" width="100" height="120" class="dummy">

  <script>
    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
    }

    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
    }
  </script>

  <div id="fullPage">
    <div class="section s1" id="section1" class="fontsize">
      <h1 style="color:white;font-size:80px;z-index:999!important;"><strong>title</strong></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="section s2" id="section2">
      <h1><strong>title</strong></h1>
      <p class="container">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel libero eget quam dignissim blandit. Pellentesque ultrices tortor id nulla cursus, vel imperdiet lorem hendrerit. Phasellus pharetra lacus id molestie dictum. In odio sem, porttitor
        vitae convallis hendrerit, ullamcorper quis enim. Donec aliquet lobortis egestas. Vivamus placerat imperdiet mattis. Quisque tincidunt facilisis diam. Nunc sodales cursus mi id condimentum. Ut blandit mattis velit. Aenean in posuere orci.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="section s3" id="section3">
      <div class="row" id="jema">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
          <img src="images/dummy.png" alt="dummy" class="responsive" width="999" height="600">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h1> Lorem ipsum</h1>
          <p class="container">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" id="jama">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
          <img src="images/dummy.jpg" alt="dummy" class="responsive" width="333" height="200">
          <img src="images/dummy.jpg" alt="dummy" class="responsive" width="333" height="200">
          <img src="images/dummy.jpg" alt="dummy" class="responsive" width="333" height="200">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section s4" id="section4">
      <footer>
        <h1>title</h1>
        <h1>Contact information: ---</h1>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.8/fullpage.min.js" integrity="sha256-caNcSA0LvOCX90PTuEbwl+V09xPMca13CJUasl+VCtk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script>
    new fullpage('#fullPage', {
      autoScrolling: true,
      navigation: true

    })
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had a very similar problem when I was constructing my website as well. I used a bunch of variables and `position: absolute`. Here's what I mean...

First, create variables with the size of the navbar you want. You can do this with the `root` pseudo class in your css file. There is a lot of css and html in your files so I will use different classes and ids from what you have. To use the root pseudoclass and create variables, do...

```
:root {
  --navbar-height: 8vh;
  --navbar-margins: 1vh;
}
```

Of course, you can change the values and the variable names. The `--` at the beginning is required to declare variables in CSS. The `:root` pseudoclass allows the variables to be accessed universally.

If you didn't know, `vh` stands for viewport height and `vw` stands for viewport width. `100vh` is always equal to the height of the screen and `100vw` is always equal to its width, so `vh` and `vw` are great units for responsive web design.

Then in the navbar, I would do something like...

```
#navbar {
  position: absolute;
  height: var(--navbar-height);
  top: var(--navbar-margins);
  left: var(--navbar-margins);
  width: calc(100vw - (2 * var(--navbar-margins));
}
```

As you can see, the syntax for declaring variables in CSS is a bit strange, but this is how it is done. The `calc()` is just how you do math in CSS. It's also strange, but roll with it. The purpose of that is to set the width of the navbar to the full width of the page (`100vh`) minus 2 times the margins (because there are margins on both sides, so we do `(2 * var(--navbar-margins))`).

Also, if you don't want top margin, don't include the `top: var(--navbar-margins)`.

`position: absolute`, in this case, does the same thing as `position: fixed`, so in this situation they can be used interchangeably. The difference is that `position: absolute` makes sure that the element stays fixed *relative to it's parent element*, whereas `position: fixed` makes sure the element stays fixed relative to the document body. However, in this case the parent element *is* the body, so it doesn't really matter which you use.

Of course, you don't have to use variables, you could just use numbers, but variables let you change all the sizes correctly just by changing one number rather than many. Also, variables become useful for the next part.

If you would like your page content to not be partially hidden by the navbar at the top, you could do something like:

```
<body>
  <navbar id="navbar">
    <!-- All navbar stuff goes here -->
  </navbar>
  <div id="content">
    <!-- The rest of your content goes here -->
  </div>
</body>
```

..in your HTML file and...

```
#content {
  position: absolute;
  /* if you want a bottom margin and have a top margin on your navbar... */
  top: calc(100vh - var(--navbar-height) - (2 * var(--navbar-margins));
  /* if you want a bottom margin OR have a top margin on your navbar ... */
  top: calc(100vh - var(--navbar-height) - var(--navbar-margins);
  /* or if you want no bottom or top margin on your navbar */
  top: calc(100vh - var(--navbar-height);
}
```

Then you can just nest your contents inside `<div id="content">`. This was super complex and long but I hope it helps! Feel free to hit me up with any questions.

Happy coding! :)

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much for going through my code :) Sorry that it is so messy because I just recently started to work with html. I have placed the #content and # navbar and root into my CSS and have placed my main code for my navbar and my main body content into the two <div> but when I try to run it it breaks my fullpage.js slider and the little navigation bar icon still pushes down the pages content. I have gotten the example for the nav bar from w3school's fullscreen overlay navigation. Thank you for your help again.

Comment: No problem! Good luck on your website!